# Parsing from multiple columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following data:

[image]

I need to find a way to parse the data and output it in some singular format such as:
[image]

It can be populated by formulas or even a pivot table... or some other method.
I have tried a few methods with no success.

Comment: Are cells **B2** and **C2** merged??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent - I edited the post to make it more realistic to my actual data which is quite long.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a kind of pivoted table, you should be un-pivoting it. The most convenient method is to use **Power Query** which is a native part of Excel for some time. If your excel version does not have Power Query natively, you may still download it and use along with Excel.

You may either open your data directly from Power Query or from Excel you may use **Data|From Table/Range** menu to send your data to Power Query.

Below you may find out how to unpivot your data in Power Query:

[Unpivot columns (Power Query)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/unpivot-columns-power-query-0f7bad4b-9ea1-49c1-9d95-f588221c7098)

After unpivoting you may **Close & Load** button, to get you final data to Excel again.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Sheet 1 if you inicial data sheet and sheet2 where you copy you sorted data;

1- If "Date", "Person", "Job", "Task" are columns A,B,C, D in sheet2 then:

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim i, j, lr, lc, newlr, newlc As Long

lr = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row '' your last row
lc = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column '' your last column

For j = 1 To lc
For i = 3 To lr

If InStr(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, j).Value, "Job") Then

Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, j).Copy

Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Cells(1, 3).Select
newlr = Selection.End(xlDown).Row '' your new last row

Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(newlr + 1, 3).Paste

ElseIf InStr(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, j).Value, "Date") Then

Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, j).Copy

Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Cells(1, 1).Select
newlr = Selection.End(xlDown).Row '' your new last row

Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(newlr + 1, 1).Paste

ElseIf InStr(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, j).Value, "Person") Then

Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, j).Copy

Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Cells(1, 2).Select
newlr = Selection.End(xlDown).Row '' your new last row

Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(newlr + 1, 2).Paste

ElseIf InStr(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, j).Value, "Task") Then

Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, j).Copy

Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Cells(1, 4).Select
newlr = Selection.End(xlDown).Row '' your new last row

Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(newlr + 1, 4).Paste

End If

Next
Next

End Sub
```

2- If If "Date", "Person", "Job", "Task" are  not current columns in sheet2 then:

```
Sub Macro2()

Dim i, j, k, lr, lc, newlr, newlc As Long

lr = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row '' your last row
lc = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column '' your last column

Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1).Value = "Date"
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 2).Value = "Person"
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 3).Value = "Job"
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 4).Value = "Task"

For k = 1 To 4
For j = 1 To lc
For i = 3 To lr

If InStr(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, j).Value, Sheets("Hoja6").Cells(1, k).Value) Then

Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, j).Copy

Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Cells(1, k).Select
newlr = Selection.End(xlDown).Row '' your new last row

Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(newlr + 1, k).Paste


End If

Next
Next
Next

End Sub
```